# Move item to first in array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of objects

```
MyObjects[] mos = GetMyObjectsArray();
```

Now I want to move some element with id 1085 to first,  so I write code like this in LINQ, is there more elegant way to do this?

```
mos.Where(c => c.ID == 1085).Take(1).Concat(mos.Where(c => c.ID != 1085)).ToArray();
```

Note, I want to save positioning of other items, so swaping with first item is not a solution

Comment: Let item with `id` you want is on `x` place. What to do with this 'empty' item? Collapse or swap?

Comment: Your code has additional properties, such as a) Creating a new array b) Removing duplicate `1085` s. c) Not throwing if such an item doesn't exist. Must these be replicated exactly?

Comment: I want to save positioning of other items, so swaping with first item is not a solution

Comment: Why don't you use a linked list for this instead?

Comment: Just we have logic in UI depending Array type, I am back end developer, and don't want to change that logic :) I know that an array is not the best data structure for the operation you are attempting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not LINQ, but it's how I'd do it with arrays.

```
public static bool MoveToFront<T>(this T[] mos, Predicate<T> match)
  {
    if (mos.Length == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    var idx = Array.FindIndex(mos, match);
    if (idx == -1)
    {
      return false;
    }
    var tmp = mos[idx];
    Array.Copy(mos, 0, mos, 1, idx);
    mos[0] = tmp;
    return true;
  }
```

Usage:

```
MyObject[] mos = GetArray();
mos.MoveToFront(c => c.ID == 1085);
```

Comment: I might be nitpicking but there's one too many a's in the first line :)

Comment: What for return `bool` if you can `void` and throw exceptions?

Comment: What exception would you recommend throwing in the event that no item is found? ArgumentException? InvalidOperationException?

Answer (score 2):

An array is not the best data structure for the operation you are attempting, it will potentially require copying a lot of items.  For what you are doing you should use a List.

First, define a List extension method as follows:

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    public static bool MoveToFront<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        int idx = list.FindIndex(match);

        if (idx != -1)
        {
            if (idx != 0) // move only if not already in front
            {
                T value = list[idx]; // save matching value
                list.RemoveAt(idx); // remove it from original location
                list.Insert(0, value); // insert in front
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false; // matching value not found
    }
}
```

Then you can use the MoveToFront extension method (modified from your example):

```
List<int> mos = GetMyObjectsList();
mos.MoveToFront(i => i == 1085);
```

Comment: Note that, under the covers, List also uses an array. So this won't be any faster than a for-loop solution. Just easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
// input array
T[] arr = Get();

// find the item
int index = Array.FindIndex(arr, i => i.ID == 1085);
if (index == -1)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();

// get the item
T item = arr[index];

// place the item to the first position
T[] result = new T[arr.Length];
result[0] = item;

// copy items before the index
if (index > 0)
    Array.Copy(arr, 0, result, 1, index);

// copy items after the index
if (index < arr.Length)
    Array.Copy(arr, index + 1, result, index + 1, arr.Length - index - 1);

return result;
```